# Swift - 2 tableviews and detailviewcontroller

Tags: swift

have problem with 2 tableviews on 2 viewcontrollers and detailviewcontroller, everything is almost working ok, 2 tableviews working like a charm, but problem is in secondviewcontroller where i put array of images to segue to detailVC after each meal/food is clicked, i got same 3 images for mexican food, spanish food, italian, croatian and french. Images(15) does to correspond to 15 meals. Did i go wrong with putting array of images in second view controller? Thank you

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

let textForFirstTableView = ["Italian food", "Mexican food", "Croatian food", "Spanish food", "French food"]

let namesOfFood = [["Bolognese", "Milagnese","Pizza"],
                   ["Tortilla", "Chimichanga", "Paella"],
                   ["Burek od mesa","Grah", "Janjetina"],
                   ["Tapas", "Churros", "Flan"],
                   ["Buche de Noel", "Cherry Cake", "Onion Soup"]]

var ObjectNamesOfFood = [String]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return textForFirstTableView.count

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = textForFirstTableView[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    self.ObjectNamesOfFood = self.namesOfFood[indexPath.row]

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let driver = segue.destinationViewController as! DrugiViewController

    var whatToPass = self.ObjectNamesOfFood

    driver.arrayToPass = whatToPass


}
}
```

SecondViewController

```
import UIKit

class DrugiViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

var arrayToPass:[String] = [String]()

var picturesForEachMeal = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"]

var objectpicturesForEachMeal:String!


@IBOutlet weak var tableView2: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tableView2.delegate = self
    self.tableView2.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return arrayToPass.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayToPass[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

     self.objectpicturesForEachMeal = self.picturesForEachMeal[indexPath.row]

     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDetailViewController", sender: self)

}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    let driver = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

    driver.picturesToRetrieve = objectpicturesForEachMeal

}
}
```

DetailViewController (displaying 15 images for 15 meals)

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var slika: UIImageView!

var picturesToRetrieve:String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var connection = self.picturesToRetrieve
    self.slika.image = UIImage(named: connection)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: I am confuse, your app has 5 countries, table view 1 pass a index between 1 and 5 to second view controller, second view controller has always 3 dishes, so it will always pass a value between 1 and 3 to the view controller. So the only thing you can see in the second view controller is the first 3 dishes

Comment: yea,  i have 15 foods coresponding to  5 countries, italian has 3, mexican has own 3, spanish has own 3 and so on, and how to display image for each food, i have 15 images and only 3 is displayed. So when i click on mexican food, and click then on tortilla, how ti display picture of tortilja, it displays only index 0,1,2 of array of images, how to display 15 images to each food, ty

Comment: I put an explanation bellow in how to implement a fix for your implementation and also a explanation in how I would approach the problem. I hope you can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In View Controller store the selected index and pass it to DrugiViewController

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.ObjectNamesOfFood = self.namesOfFood[indexPath.row]
    self.selectedKitchen = indexPath.row 
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue", sender: self)
}
```

In DrugiViewController calculate each food image index

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     var totalIndex = (indexPath.row) + (selectedKitchen * 3)
     self.objectpicturesForEachMeal = self.picturesForEachMeal[totalIndex]
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDetailViewController", sender: self)
}
```

that's it

Answer (score 1):

I must say this is not the best approach if you was starting an app from begining you should in your case use an dictionary of array that contain a key country and as result an array of dictionary dish and photo in the first view controller.
In the second view controller you should have an array of dictionary that contain the dish and photo.
In the third view just a simple dictionary that contain a dictionary with dish and photo.

But how you almost finish the easier solution for you is to pass the value from the first table to the second, so lets say if the user selected row 2 you pass and keep that values.

Now in the second table if the user selected row 3 you multiply the number of the row the user selected (3) by the number of the first row select in table view one (2) and you know you have to display the picture number 6 in your final array.

I hope this helps you, I am sure now that you know the idea you will be able to finish your project. Best of luck!

First view controller:

```
var rowSelected:Int?
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.ObjectNamesOfFood = self.namesOfFood[indexPath.row]
    self.rowSelected = indexPath.row
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue", sender: self)
}
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let driver = segue.destinationViewController as! DrugiViewController
    var whatToPass = self.ObjectNamesOfFood
    driver.arrayToPass = whatToPass
    driver.rowSelected = rowSelected
}
```

Second view controller:

```
var rowSelected:Int?
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
     self.objectpicturesForEachMeal = self.picturesForEachMeal[indexPath.row * self.rowSelected]
     self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDetailViewController", sender: self)
}
```

This is the basic idea, sorry I couldn't test it as I am in a Windows computer now, but should just work

Comment: thanks a lot, but your easier answer is a little hard to understand,  i'm a beginner in swift and i'm already almost confused with this app, thx again for trying to help, so if i move array of images to first view controller, then i also got a problem how to "merge" index 0-15 to index 0-5 in array of names, yea, problem,..

Comment: Just forget about the first part and implement the second, pass the row number from vc1 to vc2, multiply the row number you pass with the new row number select in vc2 and pass to your view, now you have the correct value

Comment: sorry for bothering you, i googled how to pass row numbers in swift  but can't find anything related, and i never done that before especially multiplying row.

Comment: I succesfully implemented your code, but now it's displaying different  pictures on different meals, like indexes of pictures does not match indexes of meals.

Comment: you need to figure out the order in your array to show the correct photo now, just change it as need to match

Comment: yea, i allready try that but it keeps repeating indexes, so first picture on index 0 is displaying on different meals, take a look at project if you have time, thank you  https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/a6977845ed2927ee89ebbd0102efde2220150610102539/bb2e89b94ee5c933d525d5be65a558a020150610102539/7469f8